# Which is the best way to check if there is already a user visiting a range of pages in a Web app?

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2

I have a Web application where I need to restrict the access to certain pages if there is already another registered user visiting those pages. If so, the other user only would have read access.

Which is the best way to implement this?

Comment: This concept is known as a long transaction with pessimistic locking. It is rare to see this in web applications. To quote from the Hibernate manual: "In order to reduce lock contention in the database, a database transaction has to be as short as possible. Long database transactions will prevent your application from scaling to a highly concurrent load. It is not recommended that you hold a database transaction open during user think time until the unit of work is complete." Also, your lock granularity might be unnecessarily large. I would recommend that you use optimistic locking instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this **[stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733437/scriptlets-in-a-jsp-page-to-access-an-authorization-framework-using-enums)**  , I think you can use the same way in your application also.

Or you can use **[Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)** .

From [**Apache Shiro Documentation**](http://shiro.apache.org/java-authorization-guide.html) :

> Authorization in Shiro can be handled in four ways.
>
> 1. **Programmatically** - You can perform authorization checks in your java code with structures like if and else blocks.
> 2. **JDK annotations** - You can attach an authorization annotation to your Java methods
> 3. **JSP/GSP TagLibs** - You can control jsp or gsp page output based on roles and permissions